# How to get mails from a particular folder in outlook c#

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I am using the below code to get the mails from the inbox folder and it is working fine for me

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;


            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            //ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);

            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) ;
            
            var list = new List<string>();
            //System.IO.StreamWriter strm = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:/Test/Inbox.txt");
            for (int counter = inboxFolder.Items.Count; counter > 0; counter--)
            {
               
                    dynamic item = inboxFolder.Items[counter];
                    string SB = item.Subject.ToUpper();
            }
```

I want to get the data from a specific folder called "Career" which was created by me where all the mails are forwarded by a rule. I want to read all the mails from the folder "Career" as shown in the picture but not sure how to do it.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is on the same level as your Inbox, use

```
yourOtherFodler = ((MAPIFolder)inboxFolder.Parent).Folders["Career"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is the exact thing I needed.